# Facebook post to feed to open in a window

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, feed

As of right now, this javascript:

```
<script>

  FB.init({appId: "123456789", status: true, cookie: true, xfbml:true });

  function postToFeed(description) {

    var obj = {
        method: 'feed',
        redirect_uri: 'http://thelivesite.com/',
        link: 'https://thelivesite.com/',
        picture: 'https://www.thelivesite.com/static/images/logo.png',
        name: 'TheLiveSite',
        caption: 'Here's a caption',
        description: description,
    };


    function callback(response) {
      document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];
    }

    FB.ui(obj, callback);
  }

</script>

 <div id='fb-root'></div>

<p style="position: absolute;">
     <a onclick='postToFeed("{{ item.title }}."); return false;'>Share</a>
</p>
<p id='msg'></p>
```

renders a box like this:

[image]

What do I have to do to make it a popout window dialog like this?:

[image]

Comment: As per your UI, Facebook support on mobile. For more details go to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this: `display: "popup`"

```
var obj = {
    method: 'feed',
    redirect_uri: 'http://thelivesite.com/',
    link: 'https://thelivesite.com/',
    picture: 'https://www.thelivesite.com/static/images/logo.png',
    name: 'TheLiveSite',
    caption: "Here's a caption",
    description: description,
    display: "popup"
};
```

Comment: Well thanks, glad I could help you out. Btw if this answer suited you mark as the right answer for future viewers

Comment: Time restriction :P YOu responded so quickly!